# Radar chart library similar to nv-d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js, radar-chart

I am using the fantastic nvd3.js library. I need a radar chart, but unfortunately radar charts are not in the nvd3 library and it [is not planned](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/issues/108) to include them in the short term

Anybody can recommend a radar chart library with a similar look and feel as nvd3?

Answer (score 1):

Here is **another D3.js based Radar Chart** library.

[image]

An Example code:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
  <title>Radar chart</title>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="RadarChart.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
          overflow: hidden;
          margin: 0;
          font-size: 14px;
          font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica;
        }

        #chart {
          position: absolute;
          top: 50px;
          left: 100px;
        }   
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="body">
      <div id="chart"></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

**RadarChart.js**

```
var RadarChart = {
  draw: function(id, d, options){
  var cfg = {
     radius: 5,
     w: 600,
     h: 600,
     factor: 1,
     factorLegend: .85,
     levels: 3,
     maxValue: 0,
     radians: 2 * Math.PI,
     opacityArea: 0.5,
     ToRight: 5,
     TranslateX: 80,
     TranslateY: 30,
     ExtraWidthX: 100,
     ExtraWidthY: 100,
     color: d3.scale.category10()
    };

    if('undefined' !== typeof options){
      for(var i in options){
        if('undefined' !== typeof options[i]){
          cfg[i] = options[i];
        }
      }
    }
    cfg.maxValue = Math.max(cfg.maxValue, d3.max(d, function(i){return d3.max(i.map(function(o){return o.value;}))}));
    var allAxis = (d[0].map(function(i, j){return i.axis}));
    var total = allAxis.length;
    var radius = cfg.factor*Math.min(cfg.w/2, cfg.h/2);
    var Format = d3.format('%');
    d3.select(id).select("svg").remove();

    var g = d3.select(id)
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", cfg.w+cfg.ExtraWidthX)
            .attr("height", cfg.h+cfg.ExtraWidthY)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + cfg.TranslateX + "," + cfg.TranslateY + ")");
            ;

    var tooltip;

    //Circular segments
    for(var j=0; j<cfg.levels-1; j++){
      var levelFactor = cfg.factor*radius*((j+1)/cfg.levels);
      g.selectAll(".levels")
       .data(allAxis)
       .enter()
       .append("svg:line")
       .attr("x1", function(d, i){return levelFactor*(1-cfg.factor*Math.sin(i*cfg.radians/total));})
       .attr("y1", function(d, i){return levelFactor*(1-cfg.factor*Math.cos(i*cfg.radians/total));})
       .attr("x2", function(d, i){return levelFactor*(1-cfg.factor*Math.sin((i+1)*cfg.radians/total));})
       .attr("y2", function(d, i){return levelFactor*(1-cfg.factor*Math.cos((i+1)*cfg.radians/total));})
       .attr("class", "line")
       .style("stroke", "grey")
       .style("stroke-opacity", "0.75")
       .style("stroke-width", "0.3px")
       .attr("transform", "translate(" + (cfg.w/2-levelFactor) + ", " + (cfg.h/2-levelFactor) + ")");
    }

    //Text indicating at what % each level is
    for(var j=0; j<cfg.levels; j++){
      var levelFactor = cfg.factor*radius*((j+1)/cfg.levels);
      g.selectAll(".levels")
       .data([1]) //dummy data
       .enter()
       .append("svg:text")
       .attr("x", function(d){return levelFactor*(1-cfg.factor*Math.sin(0));})
       .attr("y", function(d){return levelFactor*(1-cfg.factor*Math.cos(0));})
       .attr("class", "legend")
       .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
       .style("font-size", "10px")
       .attr("transform", "translate(" + (cfg.w/2-levelFactor + cfg.ToRight) + ", " + (cfg.h/2-levelFactor) + ")")
       .attr("fill", "#737373")
       .text(Format((j+1)*cfg.maxValue/cfg.levels));
    }

    series = 0;

    var axis = g.selectAll(".axis")
            .data(allAxis)
            .enter()
            .append("g")
            .attr("class", "axis");

    axis.append("line")
        .attr("x1", cfg.w/2)
        .attr("y1", cfg.h/2)
        .attr("x2", function(d, i){return cfg.w/2*(1-cfg.factor*Math.sin(i*cfg.radians/total));})
        .attr("y2", function(d, i){return cfg.h/2*(1-cfg.factor*Math.cos(i*cfg.radians/total));})
        .attr("class", "line")
        .style("stroke", "grey")
        .style("stroke-width", "1px");

    axis.append("text")
        .attr("class", "legend")
        .text(function(d){return d})
        .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
        .style("font-size", "11px")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("dy", "1.5em")
        .attr("transform", function(d, i){return "translate(0, -10)"})
        .attr("x", function(d, i){return cfg.w/2*(1-cfg.factorLegend*Math.sin(i*cfg.radians/total))-60*Math.sin(i*cfg.radians/total);})
        .attr("y", function(d, i){return cfg.h/2*(1-Math.cos(i*cfg.radians/total))-20*Math.cos(i*cfg.radians/total);});


    d.forEach(function(y, x){
      dataValues = [];
      g.selectAll(".nodes")
        .data(y, function(j, i){
          dataValues.push([
            cfg.w/2*(1-(parseFloat(Math.max(j.value, 0))/cfg.maxValue)*cfg.factor*Math.sin(i*cfg.radians/total)), 
            cfg.h/2*(1-(parseFloat(Math.max(j.value, 0))/cfg.maxValue)*cfg.factor*Math.cos(i*cfg.radians/total))
          ]);
        });
      dataValues.push(dataValues[0]);
      g.selectAll(".area")
                     .data([dataValues])
                     .enter()
                     .append("polygon")
                     .attr("class", "radar-chart-serie"+series)
                     .style("stroke-width", "2px")
                     .style("stroke", cfg.color(series))
                     .attr("points",function(d) {
                         var str="";
                         for(var pti=0;pti<d.length;pti++){
                             str=str+d[pti][0]+","+d[pti][2]+" ";
                         }
                         return str;
                      })
                     .style("fill", function(j, i){return cfg.color(series)})
                     .style("fill-opacity", cfg.opacityArea)
                     .on('mouseover', function (d){
                                        z = "polygon."+d3.select(this).attr("class");
                                        g.selectAll("polygon")
                                         .transition(200)
                                         .style("fill-opacity", 0.1); 
                                        g.selectAll(z)
                                         .transition(200)
                                         .style("fill-opacity", .7);
                                      })
                     .on('mouseout', function(){
                                        g.selectAll("polygon")
                                         .transition(200)
                                         .style("fill-opacity", cfg.opacityArea);
                     });
      series++;
    });
    series=0;


    d.forEach(function(y, x){
      g.selectAll(".nodes")
        .data(y).enter()
        .append("svg:circle")
        .attr("class", "radar-chart-serie"+series)
        .attr('r', cfg.radius)
        .attr("alt", function(j){return Math.max(j.value, 0)})
        .attr("cx", function(j, i){
          dataValues.push([
            cfg.w/2*(1-(parseFloat(Math.max(j.value, 0))/cfg.maxValue)*cfg.factor*Math.sin(i*cfg.radians/total)), 
            cfg.h/2*(1-(parseFloat(Math.max(j.value, 0))/cfg.maxValue)*cfg.factor*Math.cos(i*cfg.radians/total))
        ]);
        return cfg.w/2*(1-(Math.max(j.value, 0)/cfg.maxValue)*cfg.factor*Math.sin(i*cfg.radians/total));
        })
        .attr("cy", function(j, i){
          return cfg.h/2*(1-(Math.max(j.value, 0)/cfg.maxValue)*cfg.factor*Math.cos(i*cfg.radians/total));
        })
        .attr("data-id", function(j){return j.axis})
        .style("fill", cfg.color(series)).style("fill-opacity", .9)
        .on('mouseover', function (d){
                    newX =  parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('cx')) - 10;
                    newY =  parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('cy')) - 5;

                    tooltip
                        .attr('x', newX)
                        .attr('y', newY)
                        .text(Format(d.value))
                        .transition(200)
                        .style('opacity', 1);

                    z = "polygon."+d3.select(this).attr("class");
                    g.selectAll("polygon")
                        .transition(200)
                        .style("fill-opacity", 0.1); 
                    g.selectAll(z)
                        .transition(200)
                        .style("fill-opacity", .7);
                  })
        .on('mouseout', function(){
                    tooltip
                        .transition(200)
                        .style('opacity', 0);
                    g.selectAll("polygon")
                        .transition(200)
                        .style("fill-opacity", cfg.opacityArea);
                  })
        .append("svg:title")
        .text(function(j){return Math.max(j.value, 0)});

      series++;
    });
    //Tooltip
    tooltip = g.append('text')
               .style('opacity', 0)
               .style('font-family', 'sans-serif')
               .style('font-size', '13px');
  }
};
```

**Script.js**

```
var w = 500,
    h = 500;

var colorscale = d3.scale.category10();

//Legend titles
var LegendOptions = ['Smartphone','Tablet'];

//Data
var d = [
          [
            {axis:"Email",value:0.59},
            {axis:"Social Networks",value:0.56},
            {axis:"Internet Banking",value:0.42},
            {axis:"News Sportsites",value:0.34},
            {axis:"Search Engine",value:0.48},
            {axis:"View Shopping sites",value:0.14},
            {axis:"Paying Online",value:0.11},
            {axis:"Buy Online",value:0.05},
            {axis:"Stream Music",value:0.07},
            {axis:"Online Gaming",value:0.12},
            {axis:"Navigation",value:0.27},
            {axis:"App connected to TV program",value:0.03},
            {axis:"Offline Gaming",value:0.12},
            {axis:"Photo Video",value:0.4},
            {axis:"Reading",value:0.03},
            {axis:"Listen Music",value:0.22},
            {axis:"Watch TV",value:0.03},
            {axis:"TV Movies Streaming",value:0.03},
            {axis:"Listen Radio",value:0.07},
            {axis:"Sending Money",value:0.18},
            {axis:"Other",value:0.07},
            {axis:"Use less Once week",value:0.08}
          ],[
            {axis:"Email",value:0.48},
            {axis:"Social Networks",value:0.41},
            {axis:"Internet Banking",value:0.27},
            {axis:"News Sportsites",value:0.28},
            {axis:"Search Engine",value:0.46},
            {axis:"View Shopping sites",value:0.29},
            {axis:"Paying Online",value:0.11},
            {axis:"Buy Online",value:0.14},
            {axis:"Stream Music",value:0.05},
            {axis:"Online Gaming",value:0.19},
            {axis:"Navigation",value:0.14},
            {axis:"App connected to TV program",value:0.06},
            {axis:"Offline Gaming",value:0.24},
            {axis:"Photo Video",value:0.17},
            {axis:"Reading",value:0.15},
            {axis:"Listen Music",value:0.12},
            {axis:"Watch TV",value:0.1},
            {axis:"TV Movies Streaming",value:0.14},
            {axis:"Listen Radio",value:0.06},
            {axis:"Sending Money",value:0.16},
            {axis:"Other",value:0.07},
            {axis:"Use less Once week",value:0.17}
          ]
        ];

//Options for the Radar chart, other than default
var mycfg = {
  w: w,
  h: h,
  maxValue: 0.6,
  levels: 6,
  ExtraWidthX: 300
}

//Call function to draw the Radar chart
//Will expect that data is in %'s
RadarChart.draw("#chart", d, mycfg);

////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////// Initiate legend ////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////

var svg = d3.select('#body')
    .selectAll('svg')
    .append('svg')
    .attr("width", w+300)
    .attr("height", h)

//Create the title for the legend
var text = svg.append("text")
    .attr("class", "title")
    .attr('transform', 'translate(90,0)') 
    .attr("x", w - 70)
    .attr("y", 10)
    .attr("font-size", "12px")
    .attr("fill", "#404040")
    .text("What % of owners use a specific service in a week");

//Initiate Legend   
var legend = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .attr("height", 100)
    .attr("width", 200)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(90,20)') 
    ;
    //Create colour squares
    legend.selectAll('rect')
      .data(LegendOptions)
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", w - 65)
      .attr("y", function(d, i){ return i * 20;})
      .attr("width", 10)
      .attr("height", 10)
      .style("fill", function(d, i){ return colorscale(i);})
      ;
    //Create text next to squares
    legend.selectAll('text')
      .data(LegendOptions)
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .attr("x", w - 52)
      .attr("y", function(d, i){ return i * 20 + 9;})
      .attr("font-size", "11px")
      .attr("fill", "#737373")
      .text(function(d) { return d; })
      ;
```

Live Example: http://bl.ocks.org/nbremer/6506614

Answer (score 0):

The only radar chart library for D3 I'm aware of is [radar-chart-d3](https://github.com/alangrafu/radar-chart-d3). It's not really that similar to NVD3, but easy enough to use.